# .net Observable 'ObserveOn' a background thread

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, observable

I am trying to implement a simple Observer pattern using .net `Observable` class. I have code that looks like this:

```
Observable.FromEventPattern<PropertyChangedEventArgs>(
    Instance.User,
    "PropertyChanged")
          .Where(e => e.EventArgs.PropertyName == "FirstName")
          .ObserveOn(Scheduler.ThreadPool)
          .Subscribe(search => OnFirstNameChanged(search.EventArgs));

Observable.FromEventPattern<PropertyChangedEventArgs>(
    Instance.User,
    "PropertyChanged")
          .Where(e => e.EventArgs.PropertyName == "LastName")
          .ObserveOn(Scheduler.ThreadPool)
          .Subscribe(search => OnLastNameChanged(search.EventArgs));
```

I want the observers to run on a background thread, but I want them to all run on the same background thread (for our real implementation, it will be too complicated to have every listener on a different thread).

i.e. I want all of the `OnXXXChanged` logic to be performed on a thread other than the UI thread, but instead of `Observing` on the entire threadpool, I want to make sure they run in the correct order, on the same thread.

How should the above be modified?

Also, on a somewhat related note, are there any good sample code examples using the `Observable` class to implement this pattern?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should create an [EventLoopScheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.concurrency.eventloopscheduler%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) and use that single instance in all calls to `ObserverOn`:

```
var scheduler = new EventLoopScheduler(ts => new Thread(ts));

... .ObserveOn(scheduler). ...
```

The thread created by the factory method is the thread used to schedule the execution on. By leaving the property `ExitIfEmpty` set to `false` this thread will not terminate even if there is nothing to do meaning that it will be reused for every call.

However, you could also consider using `Scheduler.NewThread`. Using that scheduler will allow the thread to terminate if there is nothing more to do. When more work is queued up by `ObserverOn` a new thread will be created but only a single thread should ever exists meaning that you don't have synchronize different observers.

The threads created by `EventLoopScheduler` (which is used by `Scheduler.NewThread`) are named `Event Loop #`. You will see these names in the debugger.

Comment: The EventLoopScheduler implements IDisposable so you will be responsible for disposing of it. You can use the Using observable factory method to tie the lifetime to the subscription.

Comment: Scheduler.NewThread is deprecated right now, you should use NewThreadScheduler.Default instead.

Comment: Beware of using the answer above without a slight modification. Must set `IsBackground=true`, for example: `var scheduler = new EventLoopScheduler(ts => new Thread(ts) { IsBackground = true });`. If this is not set, then if this thread is still active, it will prevent the process from exiting.

Answer (score 6):

`.ObserveOn(Scheduler.ThreadPool)` takes a thread scheduler which dictates the thread that the observation runs on.  It looks like for a single thread you want to use [EventLoopScheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.concurrency.eventloopscheduler%28v=vs.103%29.aspx), rather than ThreadPool.